# Prevent ASP.NET themes from auto-adding CSS files

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

Having to deal with URL rewriting, I decided to programmatically add CSS references rather than relying on the automatic behavior of ASP.NET to add all CSS files within a theme automatically to the `<head>` of an ASPX page.

I suceeded in adding the CSS file programmatically by using

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" id="CssFile" />
```

and setting the actual URL it in code behind.

**My question is:**

Is there a way to prevent the ASP.NET "engine" from automatically adding all CSS files into the `<head>` of my ASPX/master page?

(Of course, I still could go with my own folders and completely drop the App_Themes concept)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe you can tell a skin to not include the files within it, that was the killer for us when it came to using them as it referenced all the css files not just the ones we needed and we needed maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 8):

You can prevent this feature by adding the following attributes to the Page directive:

```
<%@ Page ... EnableTheming="false" Theme="" StylesheetTheme="" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head runat="server" visible="false" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the `<head>` tag from rendering?  How would this work?  You need to provide some kinda of text to explain what this does.

Answer (score -1):

`<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Front" Codebehind="Front.master.cs" **EnableTheming="false"**  %>` 
was my solution to getting around the problem.